# netcdf fortran how to retrieve the total number of global attributes

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I am trying to figure out how to discover how many global attributes a netcdf file has. By doing so, I am using the call:

```
status = nf90_Inquire_Variable(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, nAtts=natts)
```

In order to test it I created a simple example. First, it creates a file with global attributes and then it tries to read it:

```
...

! create the file
call check( nf90_create("test.nc", NF90_NETCDF4, ncid) )
call check( nf90_put_att(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, "date", "01/01/2021") )
call check( nf90_put_att(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, "time", "00:00:00") )
call check( nf90_put_att(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, "seconds", 1000) )
call check( nf90_close(ncid) )

 
! Read the file.
status = nf90_open("test.nc", NF90_NOWRITE, ncid)
call check(status)

! how many global attributes?
status = nf90_Inquire_Variable(ncid, NF90_GLOBAL, nAtts=natts)
call check(status)

! bye
status = nf90_close(ncid)
call check(status)
```

The netcdf file is properly created

```
netcdf simpletest {

// global attributes:
        :date = "01/01/2021" ;
        :time = "00:00:00" ;
        :seconds = 1000 ;
}
```

But the following error shows up:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f34c7156d01 in ???
#1  0x7f34c7155ed5 in ???
#2  0x7f34c6e2020f in ???
#3  0x7f34c749304e in nf_inq_var_
    at /to/some/path/netcdf-fortran-4.5.1/fortran/nf_genvar.f90:181
#4  0x7f34c74ebedf in __netcdf_MOD_nf90_inquire_variable
    at /to/some/path/netcdf-fortran-4.5.1/fortran/netcdf4_variables.f90:293
Violació de segment (s'ha bolcat la memòria)
```

GDB stops at:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f5e04e in nf_inq_var (ncid=1, varid=0, name=..., xtype=1077936128, ndims=1073741824, dimids=..., natts=3, _name=256)
    at nf_genvar.f90:181
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
181      dimids(1:ndims) = cdimids(ndims:1:-1)+1
```

So it seems to me I am doing something wrong. Am I using the original call in a way it is meant to?

If not, how could it be done? By reading the netcdf fortran documentation I am not able to find it.

I am using the following versions of:

- gfortran 9.3
- zlib 1.2.11
- hdf5 1.10.5
- netcdf-c 4.7.1
- netcdf-fortran 4.5.1

Edit:

As suggested  in one of the comments below, I did a couple of minimum reproducible examples with different choices as I am a bit confused regarding the options.

I also created a new fortran bindings to the nc_inq_natts call but renamed to nf90_inq_natts.

1. [a fortran file which creates and read a netcdf file](https://pastebin.com/JxUSDNs5)
2. [a c file which creates a netcdf file with 1 global attribute](https://pastebin.com/0uSB486Y)
3. [a fortran file which only read the file from point 2](https://pastebin.com/0ErVtDGH)

All files are compiled in debug mode when running.

The following outputs came up:

Create a new file (C):

```
*** SUCCESS writing example file simple_xy.nc!
```

Only read netcdf file (fortran):

```
 nf90_inquire_variable ... 
 NetCDF: Variable not found
 nf90_inq_natts ... 
 NetCDF: Not a valid ID
 Global attributes (inquire_variable(GLOBAL)):   1788528357  <-- not working
 Global attributes (inq_natts):    260315136                 <-- not working
```

Create and read file (fortran):

```
 nf90_inquire_variable ... 
 nf90_inq_natts ... 
 NetCDF: Not a valid ID
 Global attributes (inquire_variable(GLOBAL)):            3   <-- it works
 Global attributes (inq_natts):   1256308480                  <-- not working
```

The results:

- I cannot reproduce the error I first mentioned. :-/
- nc_inq_natts does not seems to work when mixed with Fortran (NetCDF: Not a valid ID)
- nf90_inquire_variables seems to work when the netcdf file is created in the same file (?). Regarding documention it is not supposed to happen.
- C example taken from github works as expected

Comment: Please show a complete example program: see [mre].

Comment: gfortran has several options that allows one to debug a program.  Try -fcheck=all to start.

Comment: Note your gdb session contains "warning: Source file is more recent than executable" which means we can't rely on what you have reported.

Answer (score 2):

```
From a thread on the netcdfgroup mail list found by googling:
```

> ```
> A variable ID of NF90_GLOBAL is explicitly allowed with
> nf90_inquire_attribute, but not with nf90_inquire_variable.  The intended
> functions for discovering global attributes are nf90_inquire and
> nf90_inquire_attribute.  With a bit of study, the F90 documentation on this
> topic seems rather clear to me.
>
> Attempting to use nf90_inquire_variable for global attributes is a
> mis-application of that function.  Furthermore, that function is probably
> returning the appropriate error code in this case, as documented:  "The
> variable ID is invalid for the specified netCDF dataset."
> ```

i.e., change the function you call to `nf90_inquire_attribute`.

Comment: in that sense, that explains why an error. But its confusing because it is not properly raising a controlled error.

Comment: Yet it does not answer how to discover how many global arguments a netcdf file has :-/. To my understanding, nf90_inquire_attribute does not allow it .

Comment: @rgrun It says at https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs-fortran/f90-attributes.html "The attributes for each variable are numbered from 1 (the first attribute) to NATTS, where NATTS is the number of attributes for the variable, as returned from a call to NF90_INQ_VARNATTS" Unfortunately I can't find any proper documentation for NF90_INQ_VARNATTS beyond what is at https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/pkg-grass-devel/2015-January/026667.html